# Qt: connect QList with QTreeView

Tags: qt, list

I have following structure:

```
 struct Example {
     QString name;
     float number;
 }
```

This structure contained in list:

```
QList <Example> myList;
```

I want to create widget, which:

1. Display list to user.
2. Allow change the fields of structures at list.
3. Allow delete and add new element is list.

The main goal is a correct synchronizing between QList and, for example, QTreeView. Can you recommend some good practice for it? Some good examples?

Comment: Why do you need a `QTreeView`? Do you want to store the tree structure inside the `QList`?

Comment: No, I don't. We need simple two column widget.

Comment: Maybe `QTableView` is your choice. You need to implement your `model` from subclass `QAbstractTableModel`.

Comment: I done it. But when I change external list with structures, QTableView don't change.